# Xaml Binding Panorama Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

This is starting to annoy me, but I must be making some very simple mistake. I currently have the following XAML code:

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" 
       DataContext="{StaticResource JourneyViewModel}">
    <phone:Panorama Title="Journeys" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding journeys}">
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" />
        </DataTemplate>

    </phone:Panorama>
</Grid>
```

which works until I need to initialize the textblock with the name. I have items that are provided by the "journeys" parameters. However, I want to extract the name of the journey and put it into the textblock which simply is not working. My guess is that my XAML code is not correctly done. The following are the classes used:

```
    public ObservableCollection<JourneyModel> journeys
    {
        get
        {
            //I can verify with the debugger 
            //that this is not null and 
            //the variables inside the JourneyModels are set
            return _journeyModels;
        }
    }
```

And the JourneyModel:

```
 public string name
 {
      get { return _journey.name; }
      set
      {
          if (_journey.name != value)
                 _journey.name = value;
      }
 }
```

You can correct me if I am setting up the MVVM correctly, this is my first dash at it. Please let me know if you need more code bits. I hope I make the issue clear enough. Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

Loading ViewModel:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <my:JourneyViewModel  x:Key="JourneyViewModel"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: Your `DataTemplate` code should be within an `ItemTemplate` or `HeaderTemplate` tag. `<phone:Panorama.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>...</DataTemplate></phone:Panorama.HeaderTemplate>`

Comment: @keyboardP hmmm thanks for the response. However I seem to be getting a "the attachable property 'HeaderTemplate' was not found in type "Panorama"". Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is fine but you're not able to see the `TextBlock` itself. You need to put the `DataTemplate` within an `ItemTemplate` or `HeaderTemplate`.

```
<phone:Panorama Title="Journeys" ItemsSource="{Binding journeys}">
   <phone:Panorama.HeaderTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" />
      </DataTemplate>
   </phone:Panorama.HeaderTemplate>
</phone:Panorama>
```